# Cassandra with C#: How to insert bulk over a million records of SQL into Cassandra with high performance

Tags: c#, sql, cassandra

How can I convert rows from `dataset/datatable` of SQL to `rowset` of Cassandra using C#?

Using Cassandra prepared statement for bulk insert gives the ff. error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   Values parameter have 100+ values.
>   batch.Add(userTrackStmt.Bind(values));

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, that tools that can be used for fast import of million records would depend of your SQL complexity.
If you have issues with bulk insert (you haven't provided examples of your code and table structures so I could not help you here).
You could also try:
1. [COPY](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command.
2. Use Spark Streaming API using [Mobius] (https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius). So technically, you would read the first table (or SQL result), and write data to the second table in a streaming way.